# @ElementCollection gets deleted while retrieving JPA entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity with @ElementCollection collection as follows

```java
@Entity
public class RecordLog implements Serializable  {
        ......
        ......
    private String component;
    private String entityUuid;
    private Boolean legacy;
    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "auditlog_team_iris")
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    private List<String> teamIris;

       .....
       .....
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the RecordLog entity from my RecordLogRepository interface using function

```
@Query("SELECT rl from RecordLog rl where rl.entityUuid = ?1 and rl.component = 'abcd' and rl.legacy is null order by rl.transactionDate desc")
List<RecordLog> getLatestRecordLogByUuid(String entityUuid, Pageable pageable);
```

My Service class is retrieving the entities from repository using the following call

```
List<RecordLog> recordLogs = recordLogRepository.getLatestRecordLogByUuid(uuid, PageRequest.of(0, 1));
RecordLog recordLog = recordLogs.get(0);
```

I am not making any changes to the retrieved recordLogs, Still when I come out of the function in service class, the teamIris gets deleted from the recordLog.

I have tried putting @Transactional(readOnly = true) around the function in service class as well as around the function in repository interface.  I have also tried detaching the recordLogs using entityManager.detach(recordLog); but to no avail.

When I enabled debug logs in JPA, I found the following. I was actually retrieving one RecordLog and persisting three new RecordLogs. It removed the teamIris of the retrieved RecordLog

```
    27-04-2019 18:08:50.378 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl.commit - committing
27-04-2019 18:08:50.378 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes - Processing flush-time cascades
27-04-2019 18:08:50.379 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareCollectionFlushes - Dirty checking collections
27-04-2019 18:08:50.380 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.Collections.processReachableCollection - Collection found: [com.cybersponse.auditlog.model.RecordLog.teamIris#72], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
27-04-2019 18:08:50.381 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.Collections.processReachableCollection - Collection found: [com.cybersponse.auditlog.model.RecordLog.teamIris#73], was: [com.cybersponse.auditlog.model.RecordLog.teamIris#71] (initialized)
27-04-2019 18:08:50.382 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.Collections.processReachableCollection - Collection found: [com.cybersponse.auditlog.model.RecordLog.teamIris#74], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
27-04-2019 18:08:50.383 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener.logFlushResults - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 3 objects
27-04-2019 18:08:50.384 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener.logFlushResults - Flushed: 3 (re)creations, 0 updates, 1 removals to 3 collections
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue myself and its kind of strange. In my implementation I have another Entity named Lookup defined as follows

```
@Entity    
public class Lookup {
    ......
    ......
    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    List<String> teamIris;
}
```

In my service class, I was creating a new Lookup object and was assigning it the teamIris from recordLog as follows

```
List<RecordLog> recordLogs = recordLogRepository.getLatestRecordLogByUuid(uuid, PageRequest.of(0, 1));
RecordLog recordLog = recordLogs.get(0);
Lookup lookup = new Lookup();
lookup.setTeamIris(recordLog.getTeamIris());
```

When, instead of assigning the recordLog teams directly to lookup(reference assignment), I assigned the deep copy of recordLog teams, it worked.